# LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY pela SOMA de categorias no mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando agrupar pela soma de valores de algumas categorias. Porém a informação da categoria está em outra tabela e preciso fazer um left join. Sou novo no SQL

Meu código está assim

```
SELECT t1.STORE_CODE, DATE, SALES_VALUE,
t2.BUSINESS_NAME
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.STORE_CODE = t2.STORE_CODE
WHERE DATE >='2019-01-01'
AND DATE <= '2019-04-31'
```

Meu output está assim

```
STORE_CODE DATE SALES_VALUE BUSINESS_NAME
1   2019-01-02  307504.5    Varejo  
1   2019-01-03  274842.9    Varejo  
1   2019-01-04  242439.4    Varejo  
1   2019-01-05  205547.2    Varejo  
1   2019-01-06  170200.2    Varejo  
1   2019-01-07  168212.1    Varejo  
1   2019-01-08  190944.5    Varejo  
1   2019-01-09  325084.6    Varejo  
1   2019-01-10  268306.2    Varejo  
1   2019-01-07  168212.1    Varejo  
1   2019-01-08  190944.5    Farma   
1   2019-01-09  325084.6    Farma   
1   2019-01-10  268306.2    Farma
```

Não estou conseguindo incluir o GROUP BY pela soma do SALES_VALUE e BUSSINES_NAME no código...

O output que desejo é esse

```
BUSSINES_NAME   SOMA_SALES
FARMA            XXXXXXXXX
VAREJO           XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: já tentou `SELECT BUSSINES_NAME, SUM(SALES_VALUE) ....... GROUP BY BUSSINES_NAME`?

Comment: Já tentei Ricardo. Obtive o seguinte erro: could not run statement: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column......hich is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: quando há uma cláusula `group by` na query **TODOS SO CAMPOS** do select devem, ou ser agrupados, ou também estar no `group by`.. .por exemplo, imagine que tem o seguinte comando: `SELECT A, B, SUM(C) FROM TABELA`, aqui apenas `C` está sendo "agrupado" por causa da função `SUM`, o seja, os campos A e B devem estar no group by, assim: `SELECT A, B, SUM(C) FROM TABELA GROUP BY A,B`, confira se todos os campos estão assim na sua query

Comment: Boa. Acabei de decobrir isso. Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de conseguir resolver.... Bastou retirar do SELECT as colunas que não seriam agrupadas....

```
SELECT  SUM(SALES_VALUE), data_store_cad.BUSINESS_NAME
FROM data_store_sales
LEFT JOIN data_store_cad
ON data_store_sales.STORE_CODE = data_store_cad.STORE_CODE
WHERE DATE >='2019-01-01'
AND DATE <= '2019-04-31'
GROUP BY BUSINEsS_NAME
```